# Python vs MATLAB - Treating numbers approaching machine precision

Tags: matlab, python-3.x, precision

I know there are a few posts out there with similar topics. However, I haven't been able to find anything that isn't problem specific and more general.

Please, I am not looking for a workaround - i.e. "if" statement forcing value to be zero if sufficiently close to it.

In my problem I am looking at the results of transforming a matrix into Hessenberg form (i.e. applying transforms to introduce zeros into the matrix - the details of the math aren't in question here). I originally wrote the code in MATLAB for a class and now would like to have the code in Python as well (all using basic operations - no "black box" operations here). I have successfully done so but am getting ever-so-slightly different answers with the entries that are supposed to be zero.

For example:

A few entries that should be zero report as 1.77635684e-15 and 4.44089210e-16 - which all are approaching machine precision 2.2204460E-16.

Is there a fundamental reason for this?

---

**EDIT**

To refine my question a bit...

What I end up having is a subtraction of nearly equal numbers - which I know in general is a bad idea to do - for those entries in which the value is supposed to be zero. Because they are nearly equal and very small, there is a form of a loss of precision.

Which leads me to think that there may be differences in how MATLAB and python treat such evaluations...

---

**EDIT EDIT**

Here is the output that is troubling me ("py" = Python output, "mat" = MATLAB output). I can live with differences up to the ~15th digit - this is machine precision. What troubles me is the 4th column. Here is where the nearly equal number subtraction comes into play and where we really see the discrepancies (rows 2-4 are negative of each other!)

[image: Python vs MATLAB output comparison]

---

For reference, here is my python code:

```
A = [[1.,2.,3.,4.],[5.,6.,7.,8.],[9.,10.,11.,12.],[13.,14.,15.,16.]]
test = fctns.hess(A)
print(test)

def hess(A):
# This function reduces any mxm matrix to Hessenberg form
# through orthogonality similarity transforms. For symmetric A, the
# Hessenberg form will be tridiagonal.

dumA = np.array(A)
n = np.shape(dumA)[1] # obtains n in (m,n) matrix
v = []

for k in np.arange(0,n-2):
    x = np.zeros((n-(k+1),1))
    for idx in np.arange(0,len(x)):
        x[idx]=dumA[k+1+idx,k]
    tmp = np.shape(x)[0]
    if np.sign(x[0][0]) == 0:
        tmpsign = 1;
    else:
        tmpsign = np.sign(x[0][0]);
    dum = tmpsign*norm(x,tmp)*np.eye(tmp,1) + x;
    v.append(dum/norm(dum,tmp));
    dumA[k+1:,k:] = dumA[k+1:,k:] - 2*np.dot(v[k],np.dot(np.transpose(v[k]),dumA[k+1:,k:]));
    dumA[:,k+1:] = dumA[:,k+1:] - 2*np.dot(np.dot(dumA[:,k+1:],v[k]),np.transpose(v[k]));

return(dumA)
```

And here is my MATLAB code:

```matlab
function [ dumA ] = tridiag( A0 )
% This function reduces any mxm matrix to tridiagonal form
% through orthogonality similarity transforms. For symmetric cases, the
% Hessenberg form will be tridiagonal.

dumA = A0;
tmp = size(dumA);
m = tmp(1);
v = cell(1,length(1:m-2));

for k = 1:m-2
  x = dumA(k+1:m,k);
  tmp = size(x);
  if sign(x(1)) == 0
    tmpsign = 1;
  else
    tmpsign = sign(x(1));
  end
  dum = tmpsign*norm(x,2)*eye(tmp(1),1) + x;
  if sum(x) == 0
    v{k} = dum;
    continue
  end
  v{k} = dum/norm(dum,2);
  dumA(k+1:m,k:m) = dumA(k+1:m,k:m) - 2*v{k}*(v{k}'*dumA(k+1:m,k:m));
  dumA(1:m,k+1:m) = dumA(1:m,k+1:m) - 2*(dumA(1:m,k+1:m)*v{k})*v{k}';
end
end
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. This is a fundamental "issue" when working with floating point representation of numbers. MATLAB is already "working around" this implicitly in its display of the data. The values you're asserting are zero are very likely not all exactly zero in MATLAB either, only displayed as such.

Comment: @excaza I thought about that as well. 

So I printed the values of interest in Matlab (through >> fprintf('%.15e',test)) and they are indeed 0.00e+00 while in python they are 1.77635684e-15 and 4.44089210e-16.

Comment: That double precision can store 15-17 decimal digits aside, what's the question?

Comment: A difference of the order `1e-15` is not unexpected, I would be happy with that. If you require that precious you might need to rethink the problem, in general avoid operations is very small and very large number as well mixing and matching.

Comment: @excaza  I _think_ I have narrowed down the issue and will be able to resolve my question a bit. What I end up having is a subtraction of nearly equal numbers - which I know in general is a bad idea to do - for those entries in which the value is supposed to be zero. Because they are nearly equal and very small, there is some form of a loss of precision... Which leads me to think that there may be differences in how matlab and python treat such evaluations (....does that make sense?).

Comment: The confusion is not the particulars of floating point arithmetic, it's what your question is.

Comment: I suppose my question is if Matlab and Python treat floating point arithmetic differently. My gut tells me that they do not. But, it is concerning when two algorithms that are designed to give the same output give different outputs for values that approach machine precision.

Comment: The order in which vectorized operations are carried out is not specified, so errors on the order of machine precision can change. I'll tell you more: numpy uses a vectorized version of `np.dot` that utilizes multiple CPU cores whenever it can. Then it's even easier to see that what you end up with is not *exactly* certain, but can vary on the scale of machine precision. The conclusion is the usual: don't do anything that assumes *exact* agreement of floating point operations.

Comment: It's not concerning. The magnitude of the errors compared to the data being manipulated are well within expectations of operations on floating point numbers. There is no *loss* of precision here.

Comment: 1. your python code has several errors; both syntactical and semantical. No way that runs in its current form; 2. look at, for instance, your matlab solution. Compare `hess(A)` with `hess(A*3)/3`, which, obviously, should be the same. Subtract the two from each other. Check the sign of the small elements. Be shocked.

Comment: @AndrasDeak 1. You're correct. The Python code I posted in it's current form (just a copy-paste) won't work. I mostly wanted to show the function, the initial matrix A, and how I was calling the function. If you want, I can edit the post so that the code will run. 

2. Comparing the matlab solution is interesting. I suppose I'll just have to live with the reality of floating point arithmetic :/

Answer (score 2):

Your python code doesn't work as-written, and is different from the MATLAB code.  I fixed it:

```
dumA = np.array(A)
n = np.shape(dumA)[1] # obtains n in (m,n) matrix
v = []
for k in np.arange(n-2):
    x = dumA[k+1:,k:k+1]
    tmp = np.shape(x)[0]
    tmpsign = np.sign(x[0]);
    if not tmpsign:
        tmpsign = 1.
    dum = tmpsign*norm(x,2)*np.eye(tmp,1) + x;
    if not x.sum():
        v.append(dum)
        continue
    v.append(dum/norm(dum,2));
    dumA[k+1:,k:] -= 2.*(v[k] @ (v[k].T @ dumA[k+1:,k:]));
    dumA[:,k+1:] -= 2.*((dumA[:,k+1:] @ v[k]) @ v[k].T);
print(dumA)
```

I did some tests and for the first iteration, everything is identical up to the second-to-last line of the loop (the second-to-last assignment to `dumA`).  The problem occurs with this code: `dumA[:,k+1:] @ v[k]`, `dumA(1:m,k+1:m)*v{k}`.  There is a very slight numerical difference in the last element of the matrix product, about of 2e-16.  This probably comes down to slightly different implementations.

Both MATLAB and numpy seem to be using the same version of MKL for their computation, but without being able to see the MATLAB source code it is impossible to say exactly where the difference lies.

Comment: what is the     @     notation? I haven't seen that before.

Also, what is MKL?

Comment: `@` is the python matrix multiplication operator (equivalent to MATLAB's `*`).  It is available for python 3.5 and later.  MKL is Intel's Math Kernel Library, a fast (at least on Intel CPUs) linear algebra library that MATLAB uses and numpy and scipy can optionally use.  The version of numpy I tested this on, Anaconda, uses MKL.